# add a span tag to each letter, space, character from title

Tags: arrays

I try to add span tag to each letter, space, character from title. When I use `str_split` then special characters are converted to another format.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'my_title' ) ):
    function my_title( $str = '' ) {
        $output = '';
        $str = empty( $str ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title() ) : $str;

        if ( empty( $str ) ) {
            return $output;
        }

        $i = 1;
        foreach( str_split ( $str ) as $letter ) if ( $i++ <= 12 ) {
            if ( !empty( $letter ) ) {
                $output .= '<span>' . $letter . '</span>';
            }
        };

        return wp_kses_post( $output );

    }
endif;

echo my_title('Page title - with dash');
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump( str_split( 'Page title - with dash' ) );`? *special characters are converted to another format.* - what kind of another format is that? I tested your code and it worked well - I got `<span>P</span><span>a</span><span>g</span><span>e</span><span> </span><span>t</span><span>i</span>...`.

Comment: "-" is converted to "&#821;" so each character is separated in the span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because of the [`wptexturize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/) function which is being applied on post *titles*, where certain characters such as `-` (dashes) are automatically converted to HTML entities such as `&#8211;` for "beautiful" dashes.

So try this, which worked for me:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'my_title' ) ):
    function my_title( $str = '', $max_chars = 12 ) {
        $output = '';

        remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
        $str = empty( $str ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title() ) : $str;
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );

        if ( empty( $str ) ) {
            return $output;
        }

        $str = html_entity_decode( $str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < min( mb_strlen( $str ), $max_chars ); $i++ ) {
            if ( $letter = mb_substr( $str, $i, 1 ) ) {
                $output .= '<span>' . $letter . '</span>';
            }
        }

        return wp_kses_post( $output );

    }
endif;
```

### UPDATE — Notes:

Sorry @michael, I should've mentioned that I also modified the `my_title()` function to use the `html_entity_decode()`, `mb_strlen()`, and `mb_substr()` functions, so that HTML entities are properly handled. (`str_split()` is not able to properly handle multi-byte encoded string — for example, HTML entities such as the `&#8211;`)

Hence, even if the `wptexturize()` function is applied on the post *title*, the modified `my_title()` function should have no problems of handling the `&#8211;` and other HTML entities (or special characters like that). So you can, if you want, change this:

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
$str = empty( $str ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title() ) : $str;
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
```

to this:

```
$str = empty( $str ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title() ) : $str;
```

i.e. it's not necessary to remove the `wptexturize` *hook*. Just in case if you'd like to keep the "beautiful" dashes and other special characters converted by the `wptexturize()` function. =)